# Very basic form of file encryption?

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

What is a simple and effective way to encrypt a plain text file? I'm not looking for safety, I just want the average user not to be able to tamper with it. Say I have a file with newline separated email addresses. I want it to look like a garbled mess when opened, but easy to decrypt.

Comment: XOR is the simplest, completely non-secure way.

Comment: What do you mean? CURRENT_BYTE XOR NEXT_BYTE?

Comment: ROT13 is equally simple and equally non-secure.

Comment: XOR simply means flip the bits in the binary representation of each character. You can do this by taking chr( 255 - asc( c )), e.g., "A" (01000001) becomes (10111110)

Comment: XOR is probably out since you need to control the possiblily of turning a char into a CR/LF or non-7bit ASCII text. (This is because you need to read it back in and decode)

Comment: @TomZ as long as the file is read and written in binary mode, that's not a problem.  And if it was, controling the cipher can keep the encoded stream in the desired range.

Comment: Why not just encrypt it properly, with an existing tool, rather than coming up with a flawed system of your own?

Comment: The XOR cipher does not do anything against "tampering" (as in the user changing the garbled mess, creating invalid plain file). It also changes a text file to a binary file, so beware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest practical form is an [XOR cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). Basically you generate an encryption/decryption key of random numbers, of any length. To encrypt or decrypt your data, XOR the data with the key.

It is not very secure; it's mostly just used to do a light obfuscation.

```
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned __int8 BYTE;

std::vector<BYTE> xor_encryptdecrypt(const std::vector<BYTE>& encryptionKey, const std::vector<BYTE>& input)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> ret;
    ret.reserve(input.size());

    std::vector<BYTE>::const_iterator keyIterator = encryptionKey.begin();

    for(std::vector<BYTE>::const_iterator inputIterator = input.begin(); inputIterator != input.end(); ++ inputIterator)
    {
        ret.push_back(*inputIterator ^ *keyIterator);

        // advance the key iterator, wrapping to begin.
        if(++ keyIterator == encryptionKey.end())
            keyIterator = encryptionKey.begin();
    }
    return ret;
}


int main()
{
    // variable-length key of randomness, used for both encryption and decryption.
    std::vector<BYTE> key;
    key.push_back(0x55);
    key.push_back(0xae);
    key.push_back(0x8c);
    key.push_back(0x14);

    std::vector<BYTE> input;
    input.push_back(0x00);
    input.push_back(0x01);
    input.push_back(0x02);
    input.push_back(0x03);
    input.push_back(0x04);
    input.push_back(0x05);

    // encrypt
    std::vector<BYTE> encrypted = xor_encryptdecrypt(key, input);

    // decrypt
    std::vector<BYTE> decrypted = xor_encryptdecrypt(key, encrypted);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Even though just setting access permissions to world-readable and root-writeable be more appropriate.

Comment: One can recognize Base64 on first look or at least its made of ASCII chars ... doesnt look like a garbled mess ... I would prefer XOR mentioned above.

Comment: I'd have gone for Base64 too since from the sound of the question we're not after any real encryption here, just something that will look sufficiently scary to put a user off messing around with it. Ultimately Milo this just highlights that you need to settle on just how "encrypted" you want the thing to be before you settle on any particular approach.

Comment: I think it is a mistake to call it encrypted since the key (in any scheme) is going to be available (by definition) to an observer. Therefore, the tradeoff is based on how determined must someone be to recover the original text.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably just to call `srand` with a constant value,
then either xor `rand()` with each character.  Better would be to use
some available random object, which would avoid changing the global
state of `rand()`.  Decrypting is exactly the same algorithm; encrypting
twice results in the initial string.  The important thing is to always seed the random generator with the same value, and make the same sequence of calls to it.

Comment: The method is fair enough for the present, but can bite you quite badly when the random number generator implementation changes.

Comment: @thiton Good point.  You really do have to use an instance of the generator which you control (so it won't change without your approval).

Answer (score 1):

[TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) is a pretty good little encryption algorithm for basic needs, and is simple enough to implement your own version, and there are versions made in many common languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is 'keyless' scrambling, with the constraint that it should result in ASCII text and not introduce newlines.

Perhaps base64 encoding is appropriate:

[Wikipedia Base64 link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

use caesar cipher: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Answer (score 0):

Compressing a file and renaming the extension is very effective for keeping non-technical users out of files.  Unless the OS *knows* that it is a zip file, it should be relatively safe against casual binary searches.  This has the added benefit that you don't need any special tools to work with them remotely.

It isn't fool proof obviously, but the return on investment is pretty damn good.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something lighter weight than ZIP.

Comment: @IronMensan The amount of operational cost a custom file formats put on an organization is rarely worth the effort.  It's a low cost solution that meets the requirements.  I wonder what Knuth would say about zip not being lightweight *enough*. :)